# Is it possible to get the array key which references an anonymous function?

Tags: php, arrays, anonymous-function

Given an array as follows, it is possible to access the key from within the function?

```
$arr = ['foo' => function(){ echo 'I am ' /*. some variable here */; }];
$arr['foo']();
```

The ideal output here being "I am foo".

`__FUNCTION__` doesn't seem to be an option either as it returns `{closure}`.

Comment: No it's not possible! IF you use a variable as key you could pass it to the anonymous function and then use it?!

Comment: @Rizier123 that's what I was hoping to avoid needing to do ;)

Comment: I don't think you can avoid that